# How to customize the sonar widget

Tags: sonarqube

Easy steps to create plugin to customize the sonarqube

1. Create Maven project
2. Add sonar-plugin "org.codehaus.sonar" to pom.xml
3. Create own custom java plugin class and extends SonarPlugin
4. Create own widget extends AbstractRubyTemplate implements org.sonar.api.web.RubyRailsWidget and implement the methods of RubyRailsWidget
5. Add the entry of widget id of pom.xml
   CustomWidgetId
   com.siemens.sonar.CustomPlugin
6. Deploy the plugin in sonarqube /extension/plugin
7. Restart the sonarqube, click on configure widgets
8. You will find your own widget.

Comment: what is the version of SQ? If you're using a 6.X version, I strongly recommend to wait for 6.3 with a new mechanism to create pages.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question.